# Unable to Ignore maximize event from taskbar menu

Tags: c++, qt

Working on Linux Centos and my task is to ignore the maximize button event from taskbar menu for my application. Basically I dont want my application to be maximize. 
So i implemented QDialog::changeEvent(QEvent*) & EventFilter in hopes of being able to ignore the appropriate events as they come in:

```
void MyDialog::changeEvent(QEvent* event)
{
  if (event->type() == QEvent::WindowStateChange)
  {
    cout << "window state change event! window state:" << windowState() << endl;
    //should i perhaps do event->accept() or event->ignore() here?
  }
  else
  {
    QDialog::changeEvent(event);
  }
}    

bool MyDialog::eventFilter(Qobject *object, QEvent* event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::WindowStateChange && isMaximized() )
    {
      event->ignore();          
      return truel;
    }

    return QDialog::eventFilter(object, event);
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. The events are still getting through and the window is still being maximized. is there some way, any way, of solving this problem!?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isMaximized()` may not work on all window systems

From [documentation](http://ldc.usb.ve/docs/qt/qwidget.html#maximized-prop),note that due to limitations in some window-systems, this does not always report the expected results (e.g. if the user on X11 maximizes the window via the window manager, Qt has no way of distinguishing this from any other resize). This is expected to improve as window manager protocols evolve.

Comment: Problem facing on Linux Centos, isMaximized() is working on centos, When it goes for Maximize getting the event "if(event->type() == QEvent::WindowStateChange && isMaximized())" but unable to ignore the maximize event.